# Edit Auto Generated Project Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I recently Created a few projects on GitHub and decided to use the Jekyll theme to make nice pages.

I went to my Project Repository and in the settings activated the Theme Cayman and I can access the page from: `https://<username.github.io/<my_project>/`

After I also wanted to create my username page so I also created: `https://<username.github.io/`

In this repository i have my `index.html` based on jekyll css and started creating my page.

**However if I go to my Projects repository I can't find where the `index.md` or `index.html` is stored so I can modify it.**

Comment: could you let us know what the repo links are?

Comment: https://crimson-med.github.io/ and https://crimson-med.github.io/Smite-Vb/ and i would like to edit the index of the second link.

Comment: github is running `jekyll build` on the `master` branch of your repo with the `github-pages` gem. try running this locally and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smite-Vb page is being created from the README.md, so you would just edit the README file.

If you click "Project site" and look at step 4 on this site: https://pages.github.com/ you'll see they describe editing the readme.

If you want to do something different, you could create a docs/ folder or a gh-pages branch, see here for more info:
https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages

Comment: Sorry to disturb again but for the gh-pages branch I need to create it for every repo?

Comment: Yes, branches exist inside each repo so are a per-repo thing.